# jquery $.ajax automatically evaluates javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a file list, when the user double clicks a file, it is displayed in an editor, 
The problem is, after opening a javascript file, all bootstrap functions get undefined.

**UPDATE:**

```
function openFile(file){
        var filename = file.getPath();
        $.ajax({
            url: "${fileStorageServiceBaseUrl}" + applicationId + "/files/"+ resType + filename,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response) {
                editor.setFile(filename, response);
            }
        });
        openResType = resType;
        $("#saveButton").prop("disabled",false);
    }
```

After calling this function, bootstrap functions get undefined. I'm calling it from the console, not via events now.

Comment: Are you getting undefined errors? or do you mean the bootstrap javascript functions are not firing, like clicking on a drop-down menu and the menu doesnt open?

Comment: No code, no possible way of someone helping you. Theres hundreds of lines of codes onn an editor and on bootstrap's  js file. It's not like there can be a an easy way to determine what is happening, least if no code is provided at all.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm getting undefined errors.

Comment: @hsoto I'm trying to isolate the pattern but I'm failing to produce minimal code that has the bug.

Comment: When your editor is displayed are you bringing in any other javascript? And can you copy the undefined errors so we can see what they are saying is undefined

Comment: Usually, when there is an undefined error, on the console, it will state in what line of what file the error occurs.

Comment: Removing the `succes:` part of the ajax keeps the problem, but commenting the whole ajax query fixes it. I'm really clueless.

Comment: so the undefined errors happen when for instance you try to do `$("#someElementID").modal()` and the error would be `undefined is not a function` correct? Can you tell us what bootstrap functions you are trying to call?

Comment: @PatrickEvans 
`$.fn.popover`
`undefined`
`$.fn.tab`
`undefined`
and many more. I get this error all around the page after the bug gets activated.

Comment: @PatrickEvans correct. Particulary make extensive use of `popover`. But all bootstrap functions I know of are gone.

Comment: @jspurim, can you try replacing the ajax call with the `$.get` ajax shortcut: `$.get("your url",function(response){ editor.setFile(filename, response); });` and see if it causes the same problem

Comment: I just found the problem, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: BTW, I just edited the question a bit, to make it more useful to anyone finding it through search.

Comment: Yea, I should have noticed that you were trying to retrieve a JS file. This is why i asked `When your editor is displayed are you bringing in any other javascript?` earlier, because I was suspecting something was changing your original jQuery object

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yeah, I kept it, I just moved it to the intro of the question that it was an issue with js files, so it may be easy to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function openFile(file){
        var filename = file.getPath();
        $.ajax({
            url: "${fileStorageServiceBaseUrl}" + applicationId + "/files/"+ resType + filename,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "text",   // THIS LINE SOLVED IT!
            success: function(response) {
                editor.setFile(filename, response);
            }
        });
        openResType = resType;
        $("#saveButton").prop("disabled",false);
    }
```

From the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

dataType: **(default: Intelligent? Guess (xml, json, script, or html))** Type: String.
The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

**"script"** (this was getting selected by default): **Evaluates the response as JavaScript** and returns it as plain text.